# Printing elements of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to print the elements of an array. When I try a very basic W3 Schools Example, it works perfectly, but when I take the loops and variables and modify it to my application, it's acting oddly.

Basically, I have a user input. That input is pushed into an empty array. I'm using a loop to cycle through that array and print each element to the screen. If you see the pic, it's not printing correctly. I've tried three different versions of loops and all aren't printing the way I expect.

I instantiate the charNotInWordArr out of the function.

```
var charNotInWordArr = [];
```

Relevant JS:

```
charNotInWordArr.push(userInput);
console.log("the char is not in the word");
console.log("the char is " + userInput)

for (var i = 0; i < charNotInWordArr.length; i++) {
   $('#wrongGuessList').append("<li class='list-group-item'>" + userInput[i] + "</li>");
}
```

Other for loops gone wrong:

```
$.each(charNotInWordArr, function(userInput) {
     $('#wrongGuessList').append("<li class='list-group-item'>" + userInput[i] + "</li>");
});


$.each(charNotInWordArr, function(index, value) {
    $('#wrongGuessList').append("<li class='list-group-item'>" + value[i] + "</li>");
});
```

It's printing like this:

[image]

Comment: What is `userInput`? An array? string?

Comment: UserInput is a string of one character

Comment: none of those are correct loops.  1st loop (`for` loop) should be `charNotInWordArr[i]` that's printed, not `userInput[i]`.  3rd example (`$.each` with `index, value`) should just output `value` not `value[i]`.  I've never seen 2nd syntax so can't speculate.

Comment: even if I were to change it to charNotInWordArr[i] it cycles through the whole array everytime. See updated pic. So my first input, b prints. Then I input another char, 'c', then it prints bc, and then a third input 'd', it prints b,c,d instead of just d

Comment: then you don't want to loop at all.  just append an `li` with `userInput`

Comment: ha. perfect. thanks